# instead of opening php, browser downloads php in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, port

I installed php and apache2 correctly, I am able to open localhost/index.php. Index.php is located in /var/www. 
However when I open port 8000 by python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000, localhost:8000/index.php will not be opened, the browser will just to start to download it.

I also add Listen 8000 in ports.conf.

What else do I need to change to make it work properly?

One more question, what do I need to change make php work in all files not just /var/www?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve my problem. I edited apache2.conf and add 8000 port, then I change the document root to my home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You're using python to respond to the HTTP request, not Apache, so Apache never gets a chance to execute index.php.

Try [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=tutorial+configuration+apache&safe=active&ssui=on) to learn how Apache works.